# Embedded cshtml can't be found in ASP.NET Core MVC 3.0

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor

I have a library in which MVC Razor views are defined. For example `\Views\Default\Index.cshtml`. And we use this configuration in `.csproj` to reuse those views across projects:

```
<ItemGroup>
    <EmbeddedResource Include="Views\**\*.cshtml" />
</ItemGroup>
```

Now when we compile our library DLL, we can make sure that our `chtml` razor views are actually embedded inside the DLL file, inside `Resources` folder, using ILSpy.

The we use this library inside an ASP.NET Core MVC Web Application, to reuse the `.cshtml` files.

We use this line of code to register that library as a place for searching views:

```
services.Configure<MvcRazorRuntimeCompilationOptions>(options =>
{
    foreach (var assembly in assemblies)
    {
        options.FileProviders.Add(new EmbeddedFileProvider(assembly));
    }
});
```

This would work in ASP.NET Core MVC 2.2. But after upgrading to version 3.0, it's now complaining that:

```
The view 'Index' was not found. The following locations were searched:
/Views/Default/Index.cshtml
/Views/Shared/Index.cshtml
/Pages/Shared/Index.cshtml
```

What's wrong here?

**Update**: Everything mentioned in that question has already been teste by us and it's a question of 4 years ago, and has nothing to do with .NET 3.0. Also that question is not about embedded resources. It's about views in the same application.

Comment: No, it's not duplicate of that question. Our solution worked in `2.2` and it only happened in upgrading to `3.0`.